# c# resolve name in editor, ignoring case

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In VB.NET when you resolving typed name to automatically add Imports, you can type the name in lower case and VB still will find any matching combination of namespaces. And it's the only adventage of case insensitive language but still it's very usefull.

And now for my question, is there a setting or an extension that will make C# editor resolve namespace (and eventually add using) while ignore case of typed name?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, Microsoft did something good.
In Visual Studio 2015, C# editor actualy can resolve namespace from name typed without preserving correct casing which is in my opinion much more convinient and it's what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:** No, because two namespaces with the same name but different casing are actually different namespaces, which you can utilize in C# as it is case-sensitive, too.

The following definition is correct, we don't get a *duplicate definition* error for the `Test` class (in VB it would not work):

```
namespace TestSpace
{
    class Test
    {
    }
}

namespace testspace 
{
    class Test
    {
    }
}
```

For case-insensitive resolving in the editor: in C# editor both namespaces will be offered if you want to use one of the `Test` classes:

[image: Both Visual Studio C# editor and ReSharper offers namespace resolving.]

And finally, you can use case-insensitive type resolution programmatically (however, I would not recommend to use it):

```
// getting one of the Test types randomly:
Type t = Type.GetType(typeName: "testspace.test", throwOnError: false, ignoreCase: true);
```